# Consider the function $f(x)$ $=$ $\log_m(x) + \log_x(m)$ defined for $x>1$ , find the minimum value of $f(x)$ by applying the AM-GM Inequality.

Tags: calculus, inequality

> > Question: Consider the function $f(x)$ $=$ $\log_m(x) + \log_x(m)$ defined for $x>1$
> >
> > For a fixed value of $m>1$, find the minimum value of $f(x)$ by applying the AM-GM Inequality.

---

What I have started:

$$f(x) = \log_m(x) + \log_x(m)$$

$$ f(x) = \frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(m)} + \frac{\ln(m)}{\ln(x)} $$

$$ f(x) =  \frac{\ln^2(x)+\ln^2(m)}{\ln(x)\times\ln(m)}$$

Having trouble finding a way to apply the AM-GM Inequality? Also I cannot use calculus to solve this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use AM-GM for 
$$f(x)=\frac{\ln (x)}{\ln (m)}+\frac{\ln(m)}{\ln(x)}$$

Comment: I'm still confused how to apply it :(

Comment: @dydxx: Set $a=(\ln x)/(\ln m),b=(\ln m)/(\ln x)$ for $a+b\ge 2\sqrt{ab}$.

Comment: Ah yes, thank you for that. I had trouble identifying a and b. Thank you so much :)